# How to Include Supplement address line 1 to billing block on Civicrm 4.6.10?

Tags: billingblock

By default on billing block there's no supplement address line available. I would like to include this field to billing block. What is the easiest way to do it? I have looked at the Billingblock.tpl file but this particular field is not available!

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Related: *[Where to modify billing information form ≥ 4.6?](http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/2183)*

Comment: Can you describe why you'd want to do this? Payment processors are the main consumers of this data and as far as I know, they don't handle multiple address lines, so I'm not sure why you'd want to collect it.

Comment: Thats not entirely correct.... Its not a problem when i am manually typing the first address on a paypal pro payment processor and tick the box "my blilling is same as above". Now if the first block has a supplement address filled up then in billing address that line goes missing. I am talking from my experience. Many of my end users have used it....

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know this can't be done without modifying core code. The list of fields in billingBlock.tpl is hard-coded.